# JavaScript don't read the text in multiselect

Tags: javascript, html, django, m2m

I want to capture the values of a form to elaborate them in some function before to record them in the DB. I think I should use JavaScript so here we are:

My model:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    number = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=9, unique=True)
    city = models.OneToOneField(Community, blank= True, null=True)
    resources = models.ManyToManyField(Resource, blank=True)
```

My form:

```
class Crea_RegionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(initial=1)
    resources=MyModelMultipleChoiceField(Resource.objects.all(), 
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, label='Risorse')

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = ('number', 'city', 'resources')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Crea_RegionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        quantity = self.fields['quantity'] #costum field
```

My MyModelMultipleChoiceField:

```
class MyModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            '<span style="font-weight:normal">{}</span>', obj.name)
```

So the html for resources in my page:

```
Risorse
<ul id="id_resources">
    <li>
        <label for="id_resources_0">
            <input id="id_resources_0" name="resources" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 
            <span style="font-weight:normal">Turism</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="id_resources_1">
            <input id="id_resources_1" name="resources" type="checkbox" value="2" /> 
            <span style="font-weight:normal">Agricole</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        #others
    </li>
</ul>
```

and finally my javascript in crea_region.html:

```
<input type="button" value="Create" id="CreateButton" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var myform = document.getElementById("crea_region_form");
    var number = myform.number.value;

    var city_index = document.getElementById("id_city").selectedIndex;
    var city;
    if (city_index > -1) {
    city = document.getElementById("id_city").options[city_index].text;
    document.write("city: " + city);
    }

    var risorse = myform.resources;
    var selectedresources = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < risorse.length; i++) {
      document.write("risorse: " + risorse[i].text);
      //document.write("risorse: " + risorse[i].value);
      if (risorse[i].selected) selectedresources.push(risorse[i].value);
    }
    document.write("risorse: " + selectedresources);

    var quantity = myform.quantity.value;

    var button = document.getElementById("CreateButton");
    // to be completed

    //-->
  </script>
```

The problem is in resources: a costum ModelMultipleChoiceField that create a list of checkbox. My script can't read the textual and the lines

`document.write("risorse: " + risorse[i].text)` give=> risorse: undefined

`document.write("risorse: " + risorse[i].value)` give=> risorse: 1

`document.write("risorse: " + selectedresources)` give=> risorse:

### EDIT

My new script:

```
...
var risorse = myform.resources;
document.write("risorse: " + risorse[1].nextSibling.innerHTML)
console.log(risorse)
console.log(risorse[1].nextSibling.innerHTML)
var selectedresources = [];
for (var i = 0; i < risorse.length; i++) {
      document.write("risorse: " + risorse[i].nextSibling.innerHTML);
      if (risorse[i].selected) selectedresources.push(risorse[i].nextSibling.innerHTML);
}
document.write("risorse: " + selectedresources);
```

`document.write("risorse: " + risorse[1].nextSibling.innerHTML)` give=> undefined

`console.log(risorse)` give => `RadioNodeList [ <input#id_resources_0>, <input#id_resources_1>, <input#id_resources_2>, <input#id_resources_3>, <input#id_resources_4>, <input#id_resources_5>, <input#id_resources_6>, <input#id_resources_7> ]`

`console.log(risorse[1].nextSibling.innerHTML)` give=> undefined

Comment: What gives you `risorse[i]`? Try `console.log(risorse[i])` and check the output.

Comment: document.write(risorse[1]) = [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: Use `console.log(risorse[i])` and check the output in the dev console, in latest browsers, it opens pressing `F12`, in browsers such as `Chrome`, the output can be explore.

Comment: console.log(risorse[1]) = <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="resources" id="id_resources_1">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but `checkbox` doesn't have a `text` attribute, according to this [link](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/checkbox), the only attributes are: `checked`, `name`, `required`, `value`.

You will need to update your code, probably have an object somewhere in your app with `key`=>`text` so you can find the text that correspond to specific `key`, something like this:

```
var _texts = {'1': 'Text 1', '2': 'Text 2'};
var risorse = myform.resources;

for (var i = 0; i < risorse.length; i++) {
    document.write("risorse: " + _texts[risorse[i].value]);
}
```

Fill free to validate if `risorse[i].value` exist in `texts`, you can use the `hasOwnProperty` function.

Or, you can take advantage of you current html and use the `nextSibling`:

```
var risorse = myform.resources;

for (var i = 0; i < risorse.length; i++) {
    document.write("risorse: " + risorse[i].nextSibling.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: The nextSibling.innerHTML look interessing but doesn't work. console.log(risorse[1]) = undefined

Comment: `console.log(risorse[1])`????? Can you update the code in your answer with what you have now, what you are trying and where is failing?

Comment: Ops! console.log(risorse[1].nextSibling.innerHTML) = undefined

Comment: Hope before that line you have `var risorse = myform.resources;`, right? What is the output of `console.log(risorse)`

Comment: Edited first post and answered

Answer (score 0):

Done!! This look working...

My script:

```
...
var risorse = myform.resources;
var selectedresources = [];

for (var i = 0; i < risorse.length; i++) {
  if (risorse[i].checked) selectedresources.push(risorse[i].nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML);
}
document.write("risorse: " + selectedresources);
```